# GStreamer pre-recording

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to implement a pre-record
I use a shared memory of 20 seconds as a circular buffer.
I use shared memory as a circular buffer to permanently record video in it.
When an event occurs, I want to write the entire buffer to the file, and then record the video for 40 seconds.

How can I instantly encode the video from shared memory and write to a file, and then continue to write from memory to the file for some time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can ask the gstreamer queue to do the pre-buffering as follows:

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (queue), "max-size-bytes", 0, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (queue), "max-size-buffers", 0, NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (queue),
          "max-size-time", (guint64)threshold_time,
          NULL);
/* Drop old buffers when max-size-time is reached */
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (queue), "leaky", 2, NULL);
```

Install a callback on the pad of the queue:

```
gst_pad_add_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER | GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK,
                   (GstPadProbeCallback) callback, NULL, NULL);
```

Whenever you dont want pass the buffers return GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP in the callback, and when you want to pass the buffers return GST_PAD_PROBE_PASS

have pipeline something as below:

```
appsrc-- > queue --> encode --> mux --> filesink
```

Comment: Is that the src-pad or the sink-pad? I'm trying both (in gst-python) and it's not working with either. Just want to make sure I'm looking in the right place.

Comment: Its the source pad (you can get on by doing pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (queue, "src");), Note: when requesting the pad its "src" not "src-pad", queue has two pads named src and sink https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-queue.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! It seems like the data is not retained in the buffer when I return DROP. The buffers remains empty. When I return OK instead, the buffer gets filled and it is overrun when expected, however in that case the probe is no longer called. Do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: Hi @PieterJongsma, I am trying to solve the same problem as well. Did you understand what could be the cause of it?